# why my quote address will be cover by my default billing and shiping address when i come into onepage/checkout/index

Tags: magento, checkout, quote

ok,everybody,when i use A customer log in magento frontend.add some product to my cart.go to checkout.note:i just use onepage/checkout/index.let's go on 5 steps to complete my quote message.Now,special operate start.i just change sales_flat_quote table's field customer_id.Let this quote become to another customer quote message by sql.Like this:

```
  $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection('core_write');
        try {
            $write->beginTransaction();
            $quoteId=$quote->getId();
            $sql = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote`
                    SET `is_active` = '0',
                     `customer_id` = '{$parentId}',
                     `old_customer_id` = '{$customerId}',
                     `old_customer_name` = '{$sonName}',
                     `customer_email` = '{$parentEmail}',
                     `customer_firstname` = '{$parentFirstname}',
                     `customer_lastname` = '{$parentLastname}'
                    WHERE
                        `entity_id` = '{$quoteId}'";
            $write->query($sql);
            $sql="UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_address`
                    SET `customer_id` = '{$parentId}',
                     `email` = '{$parentEmail}'
                    WHERE
                        `quote_id` = '{$quoteId}'";
            $write->query($sql);
            $write->commit();
        }catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e){
            Mage::log('异常:子账号的customer_id未转换为主账号的customer_id');
            $write->rollBack();
            $customerSession->addError('place order for company falied,please try again.');
            $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/index'));
            return;
        }
```

after this，quote was become to another customer.
i use this quote_id,come to onepage/checkout/index,just magento default checkout module.when i choose addess selelct's option new address.just found in first step,my quote billing address was replaced by my another customer's default billing address.
well,i just want to magento not use my customer default billing address to cover my  original quote address message.how can?
my english is not good.pls give me some help.